# How do I stop the brief white background in Firefox when opening new tabs, even in dark mode?

Tags: windows, firefox

I run Firefox in "dark mode". If I, for example, middle-click a bookmark in the bookmarks menu, it briefly shows a 100% white background before rendering the actual page (which is dark). In spite of me using dark mode.

The same thing happens when I open a new tab; 100% white background instead of matching the dark mode. This is extremely jarring.

As with so many things, Mozilla has crippled Firefox even this regard, so that you are only allowed these two choices for "new tabs":

1. "Firefox Home (Default)". This one is ugly and "heavy" beyond words and also designed to spy on you. I refuse to have anything to do with it.
2. "Blank Page". This means 100% white even though Firefox is in "dark mode". You'd think it would mean "whatever color is the basis of the current theme"...

Just above that setting, there is a similar preference for "Homepage and new windows". This one has the same choices as above, ***but*** also a "custom URLs" one! If that option had been available for "new tabs", I could probably have fed it a local HTML file which just paints a dark background, as an ugly but workable work-around, but that option just doesn't exist. I don't know if it has existed in the past.

How can I get rid of that "flashing light" as the brief white background looks like to me countless times a day?

Comment: You can disable everything unwanted on the "Firefox Home" page so that it is just a dark page in the end.

Comment: in firefox v91, this doesn't seem to happen anymore. Home page set to "Firefox Home (Default)". I'm using dark reader, static mode. However white flash still happens on new windows.

Answer (score 4):

I recently looked for a solution to this as well after getting flashbanged at night or on dark mode. The info on this page was able to solve it for me: https://fedidat.com/640-dark-newtab-firefox/

In `about:config`, change the `browser.display.background_color` preference to a color of your choice (mine is #808080 for example).

In [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html), add the following code and replace #808080 with your color.

```
#browser vbox#appcontent tabbrowser, #content, #tabbrowser-tabpanels, 
browser[type=content-primary],browser[type=content] > html {
    background: #808080 !important
}
```

One side effect I noticed is that some web pages do not have a background color, so before they defaulted to white but now they use my gray color. Sometimes this can affect readability. The trick is to find a gray that works for you so the flash is not bright but also so that you can read pages.

Answer (score 0):

---

In the settings page, search for "Colors"
And then click "Manage Colors...", and set Background color for something dark that suits you..
And untick the "Use System Colors" checkbox and hit Ok

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: From my point of view the description was quite clear. It pointed me in the right direction to find the solution described in my answer below. Thanks Lucas Im.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox optionally uses the system colors, and if your system supports dark mode, the system window background color might be used.

Open Firefox settings by using the menu or enter about:preferences in the address bar, search for "Colors", click "Manage Colors", Check "Use system colors" and OK. Also, make sure the Color Scheme is selected automatically (i.e. not Light or Dark, otherwise the system settings for dark mode are not used).

This worked for me with Firefox 121 on Ubuntu 22.04. No more flashing white in new windows. What a relief. I have not tested with websites that do not set a background color, but for light sensitive users (aren't we all?), I recommend to use the Dark Reader extension.

Still, the Firefox developers should really adjust the background color to the selected color scheme.